# How to create programmatically CardView

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android app in `Java` & `Android Studio`.

I want to create in activity a `CardView` programmatically.
I want to set the following properties to the `CardView`:

```
layout_width="wrap_content"
layout_row="0"
layout_column="1"
layout_gravity="fill"
layout_margin="8dp"
layout_columnWeight="1"
layout_rowWeight="1"
cardCornerRadius="8dp"
cardElevation="8dp"
```

The card should be created in a `GridLayout`

```
CardView cardView = new CardView(getActivity());
```

Comment: Am I right when I say you want to do it with a loop?

Comment: Not necessarily. I just want to set those properties programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example. you can add other parameters as well:

```
cardview = new CardView(context);

        layoutparams = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        cardview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
        cardview.setRadius(15);
        cardview.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
        cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        cardview.setMaxCardElevation(30);
        cardview.setMaxCardElevation(6);

relativeLayout.addView(cardview);
```

Comment: What about the row & column that I want to set? I don't know the functions for that

Comment: CardView does not have those parameters. What do you want to achieve by those?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/w2rz73 this look.. I think it's only work if the cardView is inside GridLayout

Comment: True you need a gridview and what you are doing now is not the best way to do it. Since you wanna do it programmatically, it means you don't know how many you need. otherwise, you would just make the cardView in the xml file. So the best thing you can do is use a RecyclerView

Comment: I could use RecyclerView but I want to add different ViewCard designs (xml files) is that possible?

Comment: Yes. you can have different views in one recyclerView

Comment: Hi I have a problem with the RecylerView please look --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65308868/adding-multiple-different-cardviews-to-recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

Considering you already have written this line:

```
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
```

You can start create and change properties of your cardview like this:

```
CardView cardView = new CardView(getActivity());
    cardView.setRadius(8);
    cardView.setCardElevation(8);
```

Finally add the cardview to your gridlayout like this:

```
        gridLayout.addView(cardView);
```

Comment: What about the row & column that I want to set?What about the row & column that I want to set? I don't know the functions for that