# Is it possible to create a card view from the activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, cardview

I am creating an app in which you learn Spanish, in order to learn the words I want to create cards that one side will show the word in Spanish and the other will show the word in English
I won’t be able to know the amount of words, therefore I want to create the card views from the activity and not from the xml
Is it possible?
I’m using xamarin android in visual studio

I tried to change the text on the cardView but I wasn’t able to do so, also I think the better option is to create new cards for each word

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create create a card view from the activity. You can add the following code into the activity to create a new CardView.

```
var cardview = new CardView(this);
var layoutparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
cardview.LayoutParameters = layoutparams;
// and you can set the card view's other properties

//if you want to add the card view into the linearlayout you can use
linearlayout.AddView(cardview,0); // the 0 is the index of the linearlayout
```

For more information, you can refer to the case about [how to create programmatically CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65297495/how-to-create-programmatically-cardview)

Comment: Thank you for helping, After writing this code I got an exception saying System.NullReferenceException: object reference not set to an instance of an object, do you know how to solve it maybe?

Comment: Can you try to debug to find which line cause this error? Or could you please show the detail about the code? @RealAdamZotof

Comment: Hi, I was able to fix this problem and the code runs, but it doesn’t create the card view and it doesn’t do anything, do you have a suggestion of what should I do?

Comment: Did you add it into the layout in the xml? Or could you please show the details about using the code? @RealAdamZotof

Comment: This is the code, private void A1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinearLayout linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
            var cardview = new CardView(this);
                var layoutparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                cardview.LayoutParameters = layoutparams;
                cardview.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
           cardview.SetPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);    cardview.SetCardBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);    linearLayout1.AddView(cardview, 0);

        }

Comment: This is because you new a LinearLayout and add the cardview in the LinearLayout. You should use the FindViewById to get the linearlayout in your xml and add the cardview in it. @RealAdamZotof